# Where to find Data with site that have hazardous, toxic or radioactive substances?

Tags: shapefile, data, data-collection

Does anybody know where to find data that lists the location of sites that have hazardous, toxic or radioactive substances?

I'm working on a HUD project and need to be able to find out if sites for new housing is within a certain distance of gas stations or other places that are potentially hazardous.

Specifically interested in Florida, USA.

Comment: http://www.dep.state.fl.us/gis/datadir.htm

Comment: https://edg.epa.gov/metadata/rest/document?id={40FC2049-2639-47E1-B057-AA65C83E3EDB}&xsl=metadata_to_html_full

Comment: thanks, I looked at the dep state site several times and overlooked that dataset each time

Comment: Just make sure you are not tagged by the other kind of three-letter outfits for asking such questions...